# How to create nested object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to create an object in this format by using JavaScript.

```
var results = {
    "A-1": [
        { "object": "daily", "type": "when", "field": "Period" }
    ],
    "A-2": [
        { "object": "weekly", "type": "when", "field": "Period" }
    ],
    "A-3": [
        { "object": "monthly", "type": "when", "field": "Period" }
    ],
    "B-1": [
        { "object": "Boston", "type": "who", "field": "City" },
        { "object": "AG", "type": "what", "field": "region" },
        { "object": "L1", "type": "where", "field": "Level" }
    ],
    "B-2": [
        { "object": "New York", "type": "who", "field": "City" },
        { "object": "AG", "type": "what", "field": "region" },
        { "object": "L2", "type": "where", "field": "Level" }
    ],
    "B-3": [
        { "object": "Paris", "type": "who", "field": "City" },
        { "object": "EURO", "type": "what", "field": "region" },
        { "object": "L1", "type": "where", "field": "Level" }
    ],
    "B-4": [
        { "object": "Boston", "type": "who", "field": "City" },
        { "object": "AG", "type": "what", "field": "region" },
        { "object": "L2", "type": "where", "field": "Level" }
    ]
};

var periodList = "daily,weekly,monthly";
```

The `B-` section key values are returned from web services in JSON format as shown below:

```
 [
    { "object": "Boston", "level": "L1", "region": "AG" },
    { "object": "Paris", "level": "L1", "region": "EURO" },
    { "object": "Boston", "level": "L2", "region": "AG" },
    { "object": "China", "level": "L1", "region": "AP" },
    { "object": "New York", "level": "L2", "region": "AG" }
]
```

Each `B-` object contains the city, region and level arrays.

Please help how to create this structure dynamically?

Comment: Should `China` be in your desired JSON output? Also, is key `ojbect` in the web service returned JSON a typo in your question?

Comment: Sorry, it is typo in my returned data while I create this sample data.

Comment: China is just another sample data.  If added, another B-5 list should be created.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the the clarifications. Are the `A-` key-array pairs constant?

Comment: The A- key-values pairs are constant for "type" and "field".  The "object" values are from a constant string of "daily,weekly,monthly".

Comment: So the `A-` `object` key values should come from `periodList`, I take it?

Comment: yes. It is from the periodList.

Comment: Thanks! I just suggested some mostly ready edits to capture my understanding of your issue better. Apologies for the incomplete JSON double quote usage fix.

Comment: I'll try for a concise [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) solution; looks like @Bergi has already gotten the plain JavaScript answer up! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two simple loops:

```
var results = {};
var periods = periodList.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<periods.length; i++)
    results["A-"+(i+1)] = [
        {"object": periods[i],    "type": "when",   "field": "Period"}
    ];
for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++)
    results["B-"+(i+1)] = [
        {"object": json[i].object, "type": "who",   "field": "City"},
        {"object": json[i].region, "type": "what",  "field": "region"},
        {"object": json[i].level,  "type": "where", "field": "Level"}
    ];
```

There is no arbitrary nesting, so you don't need recursion or anything heavy.

Comment: `periods.lenght` one more typo

Comment: Thank you for your quick solution. I am much appreciated.

Comment: Hi,  What if I need to add the section A to each of B section instead?  How can I show my new format?